# Data from .CSV to JSON to Table (Table header is also dynamic) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv

In my code below `onDataChange` prop of `Form element` fetches data from .CSV to JSON via `Papa.parse` in `Form` Component and updates `data` in state of `CommonComponent`.

While loading data after choosing .CSV file `Keys: Object.keys(this.props.data[0])` shows error that `this.props.data[0]` is `null`. However, `{this.props.data.map(data=> <TableRows key={data.id} {...data}/>)}` works fine and waits for `data` to be updated and rendered, even if both of them where `null` in the beginning.

Is there any way to handle this situation? I want to use `Object.keys(this.props.data[0])` **(i.e. The keys of Array's first object)** to show table headers because for different .CSV table header will be different, and i want to render table for any size or scale .CSV.

Here's my code, I haven't shown `Form` component because, it's irrelevant.

```
const TableRows = (props) => {
    return (
        <tr>
            <td>{props.Account_Created}</td>
            <td>{props.City}</td>
            <td>{props.Country}</td>
            <td>{props.Last_Login}</td>
        </tr>
    );
};


class TableComponent extends Component {
    state = {
      Keys: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            Keys: Object.keys(this.props.data[0])
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            {this.state.Keys.map(KEY => <th>{KEY}</th>)}
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.data.map(data=> <TableRows key={data.id} {...data}/>)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class CommonComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        data: []
    };

    updateData = (result) => {
        const data = result.data;
        this.setState({data});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form onDataChange={this.updateData}/>
                <TableComponent data={this.state.data}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, Now i can show any JSON data coming to `TableComponent` via props. This is the solution for my problem, i came up after considering reply from [chbchb55](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4709300/chbchb55):

```
class TableRows extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                {this.props.keys.map(Key=> <td>{this.props.data[Key]}</td>)}
            </tr>
        );
    }
}

class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {this.props.keys.map(Key => <th>{Key}</th>)}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.data.map(data=> <TableRows key={data.id} keys={this.props.keys} data={data}/>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

class TableComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Table keys={this.props.data.length > 0 ? Object.keys(this.props.data[0]) : []} data={this.props.data}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Don't use `componentDidMount`

You're problem is that you're using `componentDidMount` to obtain the `keys` from the data object. When the component mounts there most likely won't be data yet.

Solution: Get the keys in `render`. This will work better for two reasons:

1. You won't have to worry about waiting for the data to arrive, the component will update when it does.
2. If you ever change the data, the headers will change as well.

Here is the code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        { this.props.data.length > 0 ? Object.keys(this.props.data[0]).map(KEY => <th>{KEY}</th>) : ''}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.props.data.map(data=> <TableRows key={data.id} {...data}/>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```